# How to convert raster to matrix in R to calculate evapotranspiration in R with SPEI::hargreaves?

Tags: r

When I convert from raster to points, 8 million rows are generated because I use 36 rasters with 90 meters of spatial resolution, that's why I prefer to convert it to matrix to see if it speeds up the process. But I get an error.

```
cap1 <- as.matrix(tmin[[1]])
cap2 <- as.matrix(tmax[[1]])
cap3 <- as.matrix(prec[[1]])
cap1[is.na(cap1)] <- -999
cap2[is.na(cap2)] <- -999
cap3[is.na(cap3)] <- -999
cap4 <- yFromCell(tmin[[1]], 1:ncell(tmin[[1]]))
ETp <- hargreaves(Tmin = cap1, Tmax = cap2, Pre = cap3, lat = cap4)

Error in hargreaves(Tmin = cap1, Tmax = cap2, Pre = cap3, lat = cap4) : 
  `lat` has incorrect length.
```